# zoom automático na imagem

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
.zoom {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
 max-width: 100%;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.zoom:hover img {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

.text-item {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 bottom: 20px;
 z-index: 10;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
 <img src="http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/fachada.jpg" class="img-responsive">
 <div class="text-item">
  <h2>Fachada Funerária</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Então. Para quer o efeito de `zoom` ocorra, é necessário passar o **mouse** por cima da `imagem`.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que esse `efeito` ocorra **automaticamente**.
Na verdade, essas imagens estão dentro de um `slideshow`. Por isso preciso que fosse automático.

Alguma **ideia**?
Este é o slide:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
           data-cycle-fx=fadeout
           data-cycle-timeout=5000
           data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
           data-cycle-slides="div.slide">

  <!-- prev/next links -->
  <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
  <div class="cycle-next"></div>
  <div class="cycle-pager"></div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/fachada.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_10.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_4.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_5.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_6.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_7.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_8.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="slide"> <img  src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_9.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
```

até cheguei a tentar o estilo abaixo mas não fica legal pois quando chega o final, ele volta para o zoom original e não era para voltar além de que também o zoom é feito muito tumultuado.

```
.zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
    max-width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    animation: zoom 1s; 
}
@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    }
    10% {
        transform: scale(1.01);     
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1.02);     
    }
    30% {
        transform: scale(1.03);     
    }   
    40% {
        transform: scale(1.04);     
    }   
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.05);     
    }   
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.06);     
    }   
    70% {
        transform: scale(1.07);     
    }   
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.08);     
    }   
    90% {
        transform: scale(1.09);     
    }   
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.10);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Inclua o slide em sua pergunta

Comment: feito! Adicionei ao final da pergunta!

Comment: em que momento deve ocorrer o zoom? cada vez que uma imagem para no meio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar que a animação retorne ao estado inicial, basta adicionar em `.zoom img` o código `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. Dessa forma a animação será executada apenas uma vez (sem retornar ao estado inicial).

**Exemplo Autoplay:**

```js
const images = $("div.zoom img")

function startSlider() {  
  let active = $("div.zoom img.active")
  
  if (!$(active).next().length) {
    active = images[0]
  }
  
  $(active)
    .fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(active).removeClass("active")
          .next()
          .fadeIn()
          .addClass("active")
    })
  
  setTimeout(startSlider, 5000)
}

setTimeout(startSlider, 5000)
```

```css
.zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    width: 500px;
}

.zoom img {
    max-width: 300px;
    display:none;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.zoom img.active {
  animation: zoom 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    } 
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.3);     
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoom">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=585" class="img-responsive active">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=586" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=584" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=588" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=591" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=590" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

**Exemplo com botões:**

```js
/* Imagens */
const images = $("div.zoom img")

$("#prev").click(function(){

  /* Captura o elemento anterior (do elemento ativado) */
  let prev = $("div.zoom img.active").prev();
  
  /**
   * Verifica se há elementos antes do elemento ativado,
   * caso não tenha, captura o último
   */
  prev = prev.length ? prev : images[ images.length - 1 ]
  
  /* Exibe a imagem */
  displayImage(prev)
})

$("#next").click(function(){
  /* Captura o elemento posterior (do elemento ativado) */
  let next = $("div.zoom img.active").next();
  
  /**
   * Verifica se há elementos após do elemento ativado,
   * caso não tenha, captura o primeiro
   */
  next = next.length ? next : images[0]
  
  /* Exibe a imagem */
  displayImage(next)
})

/* Função para exibir as imagens */
function displayImage(next) {
  let active = $("div.zoom img.active")

  $(active)
    .fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(active).removeClass("active")
      $(next).fadeIn()
          .addClass("active")
    })
}
```

```css
.zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
}

.zoom img {
    max-width: 300px;
    display:none;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.zoom img.active {
  animation: zoom 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    } 
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.3);     
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoom">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=585" class="img-responsive active">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=586" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=584" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=588" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=591" class="img-responsive">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=590" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

---

Ou você pode utilizar `transition` para causa o efeito.

```js
let scale = 1;

$("#aumentar").click(function(){
  $("div.zoom img").css("transform", "scale("+ (scale+=0.1) +")");
})

$("#diminuir").click(function(){
  $("div.zoom img").css("transform", "scale("+ (scale-=0.1) +")");
})
```

```css
.zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
    max-width: 300px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoom">
 <img src="http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/fachada.jpg" class="img-responsive">
 <div class="text-item">
  <h2>Fachada Funerária</h2>
 </div>
</div>

<button id="aumentar">Aumentar</button>
<button id="diminuir">Diminuir</button>
```

Comment: bacana! No primeiro slider, alguma chance de adicionar os botões retroceder e avançar?

Comment: @CarlosRocha adicionei um novo exemplo

Comment: Não querendo ser chato, mas já sendo. Esse novo exemplo fica aguardando o click em next ou prev para trocar o slide. Eu gostaria que, embora tivesse os botões, o auto play continuasse!

Comment: @CarlosRocha É só copiar o código `$("#prev")` e `$("#next")` e adicionar no *exemplo #1*.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado.

Comment: Então, só mais uma ultima coisa: como fazer para que uma imagem o efeito seja zoomIn e na próxima zoomOut sequencialmente? Ví que fez o zoonIn dentro da função zoomOut mas não funcionou.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Para não poluir, ainda mais, o exemplo acima. Resolvi publicar um código a parte no *jsfiddle*. https://jsfiddle.net/wLuv4ezp/

Comment: Oi, surgiu uma outra situação aqui. Gostaria de colocar um titulo em cada foto. Tipo uma descrição, um label. Mas aí seria necessário colcocar cada grupo,foto-label dentro de uma div ou algo assim. E desta forma estou perdendo as propriedades e está dando erro de execução do slide. Poderia fazer outro jsfiddl com essa alteração fazendo favor? Eu até tente e pode ser visualizada minha tentativa em http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index6.php

Comment: @CarlosRocha cria outra pergunta para não sair muito do assunto "zoom automática". Isso pode levar aos moderadores a fechar o tópico. Qualquer coisa me marca na caixa de comentários da outra pergunta.

Comment: Ok, feito https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296263/erros-em-slide-show