# Erros em slide show

Tags: css, css3

Algumas dúvidas:

1 ) Se reduzirmos o `height` do **navegador** alterando a resolução, a `div.slider` não acompanha a altura da `div.slide`. Ou seja, ela se mantem com a mesma altura. Logo, a imagem fica pequena, a `div.slider` alta e os **controles** próximo e anterior lá embaixo.

2 ) A **SPAN** que está as descrições das **imagens** esta acima da **NAV** que abriga os botões de navegação. O problema aqui é que eu não consigo **navegar** por causa disso. E, se eu colocar a SPAN com um tamanho pequeno e jogar ela para frente então dá para navegar, porém não consigo desta forma centralizar o **SPAN**.

3 ) Ainda há uma ultima dúvida. Mas essa é a nível de ensino mesmo.
No código abaixo tem:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Mas se eu colocar `div.slide` ao invés de `.slide`, embora seja uma **div**, o **slide** some e página carrega em branco. O que está acontecendo nesse evento?

Alguém pode me ajudar fazendo favor?

Código abaixo:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

 function startslider(dir) {
   ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")
   ativa.removeClass("ativa");
   if(dir == -1) 
  $('div.slider').prepend($('div.slider div.slide').last());
   else 
  $('div.slider nav').before(ativa);
   
   $('div.slider div.slide').eq(0).addClass('ativa');
   timer = setTimeout(startslider, 2000);
 }
 
 $('div.slider nav button.proximo').on('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  startslider(1);
 });
 
 $('div.slider nav button.anterior').on('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  startslider(-1);
 });
 
 var timer = setTimeout(startslider, 2000);
    
   });
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.fade {
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
   from {
  opacity: .4
  }
   to {
  opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
   from {
  opacity: .4
  }
   to {
  opacity: 1
  }
}

div.slider {
 position: relative;
 width: 100vw;
 height:360px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
}
.ativa {
 display: block;
}
.ativa img {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 animation: slider 1s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes slider {
   0% {
   transform: scale(1);
  }
   100% {
   transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
.ativa img:hover {
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
div.slider div.slide span {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 z-index: 500;
}
div.slider nav {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
 z-index: 400;
}
div.slider nav button.anterior, div.slider nav button.proximo {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}
div.slider nav button.anterior {
 left: 10%;
}
div.slider nav button.proximo {
 right: 10%;
}
div.slider nav button.proximo label {
 top: calc(50%-20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
   <div class="slide ativa">
     <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
     <span>Este é 1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
     <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
     <span>Este é 2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
     <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" />
     <span>Este é 3</span>
   </div>
   <nav>
     <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
     <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
   </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Valdeir PSR, está ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por parte e no final posto um exemplo da modificação.

> 1 ) Se reduzirmos o *height* do navegador alterando a resolução, a *div.slider* não acompanha a altura da *div.slide*

Fiz algumas modificações no CSS e explico o porque a *div* não acompanha a altura.

> 2 ) A *span* que está as descrições das imagens esta acima da *nav* que abriga os botões de navegação.

O problema aqui é que você está setando a largura como `100%`. Como você está trabalhando com `position:absolute`, ele acaba sobrepondo os demais. Você poderia corrigir com `width: calc(100% - 200px);` e depois corrigir a margem.

No exemplo fiz diferente. Resolvi utilizar `float`.

> 3 ) Se eu colocar `div.slide` ao invés de `.slide`, embora seja uma *div*, o *slide* some e página carrega em branco.

Como o CSS funciona em modo cascata (*Cascade Style Sheet*), ele irá interpretar `div.slide` como sendo um elemento "superior", ignorando a classe `.ativa` (que não específica o elemento que vai alterar — irá servir para todos), responsável por altera o `display`. Para funciona, é necessário fazer da seguinte forma:

```
div.slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
div.ativa {
    display: block
}
```

**Segue exemplo comentado:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    function startslider(dir) {
        /* Captura a imagem ativa e define a imagem atual */
        let ativa   = $("div.slider figure.ativa")
        let current = null;

        /* Verifica se a direção é esquerda (-1) ou direita (qualquer outro valor) */
        if (dir == -1) {
            current = $(ativa).prev();
        } else {
            current = $(ativa).next();
        }

        /**
         * Verifica se há alguma imagem ativa
         * ou se chegou no final do slide, caso
         * a condição seja verdadeira, captura
         * a primeira imagem do slide.
         */
        if (current.length == 0) {
            current = $("div.slider figure").first()
        }

        /**
         * Remove a adicione a classe "ativa"
         * no elemento ativo e atual, respectivamente.
         */
        $(ativa).removeClass("ativa");
        $(current).addClass('ativa');

        /* Captura o atributo "ALT" e adicione acomo legenda */
        $(".slider-controls .caption").text($(current).find("img").attr("alt"))

        /* Programa um novo slide */
        timer = setTimeout(startslider, 4000);
    }

    $('.slider-controls button.proximo').on('click', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        startslider(1);
    });

    $('.slider-controls button.anterior').on('click', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        startslider(-1);
    });

    let timer = setTimeout(startslider, 0);

});
```

```css
/* Reseta os atributos abaixo */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

/**
 * Adiciona "position" como "relative" para
 * não "perder" o tamanho da imagem.
 * O "absolute" não "consegue" modificar o tamanho
 * do elemento pai.
 */
.slide {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Adiciona o efeito na div, ao invés da imagem
 */
.ativa {
  animation: slider 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
}

.ativa img {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Como removi o "nav" do elemento #slider
 * Precisei adicionar as modificações abaixo.
 * Como o tamanho é fixo, não terá problema em 
 * trabalhar com o "bottom" fixo também.
 */
.slider-controls {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Nos botões de controle, não há necessidade
 * de trabalhar com "position:absolute", basta
 * utilizar "float" para posicioná-los.
 */
.slider-controls button.anterior,
.slider-controls button.proximo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

.slider-controls button.anterior {
  float: left;
}

.slider-controls button.proximo {
  float: right;
}

.slider-controls span.caption {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to   {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to   {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slider {
  from {transform: scale(1)}
  to   {transform: scale(1.1)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <figure class="slide">
    <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" alt="Imagem 1" />
  </figure>

  <figure class="slide">
    <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" alt="Imagem 2" />
  </figure>

  <figure class="slide">
    <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" alt="Imagem 3" />
  </figure>
</div>

<nav class="slider-controls">
  <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
  <span class="caption"></span>
  <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Não sei se conseguir explicar os pontos.